# Prestashop 1.7: Saving in DB the images of the products but images are not correctly shown in product sheet

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I want to fetch the images of the products of an existing Prestashop 1.6 Website and import them in a new Prestashop 1.7 Website. I'm not speaking about products variations/combinations/declinations for now, but only about the original products.

So, given the following variables, I have written the below code:

- `$ps16ProductObject` is a product from Prestashop 1.6, fetched thanks to the Webservices of Prestashop, using the Prestashop client
- `$prestashop17Product` (doesn't appear in my code for the moment) is a Prestashop 1.7 product, imported from Prestashop 1.6, that does exist in Prestashop 1.7 (*i.e.:* it's actually created and saved in DB). I want to import `$ps16ProductObject`'s images to this Prestashop 1.7 product. `$prestashop17Product` is an instance of the class `class/Product.php`, hydrated (`->hydrate()`) with the Prestashop 1.6 product `$ps16ProductObject`.

  ```
  if(array_key_exists('images', $ps16ProductObject['product']['associations'])) {
      foreach($ps16ProductObject['product']['associations']['images'] as $imagePs16Id) {
          $image = new \Image();
          $image->id_product = $ps16ProductObject['product']['id'];
          $image->position = \Image::getHighestPosition($ps16ProductObject['product']['id']) + 1;
          $image->add();
          $new_path = $image->getPathForCreation();                           
          $tmpfile = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../temp.jpeg';
          $ps16image = $this->ps16Client->get([
              'resource'      => 'images/products/' . $ps16ProductObject['product']['id'] . '/' . $imagePs16Id['id']
          ]); 
          file_put_contents($tmpfile, $ps16image);
          \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '.jpeg');               
          unlink($tmpfile);
      }
  }
  ```

**(inspired by the code of `/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php`)**

The images are correctly saved into file system and they appear in the DB tables `image`, `image_lang`, `nch_image_shop` .

The problem is that: when I go to a product sheet in BO of the PS17 Website, it "shows" the images but they are empty, as if they could not be loaded. The "empty" product image has this path: `/img/p/3/5/9/359-home_default.jpg` and there isn't any 404 error. I have compared this path to a manually-created-product sheet's image's path and my conclusion is that this path is totally correct.

What is missing and how to correct it please?

## Important Edit

There is actually a 404 error when I try to open `/img/p/XXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ/XXXYYYYZZZ-home_default.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. The important new part that made the script work is:

```
            foreach ($imagesTypes as $imageType) {
                \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '-' . stripslashes($imageType['name']) . '.' . 'jpg', $imageType['width'], $imageType['height'], 'jpg');
                if ($generate_hight_dpi_images) {
                    \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '-' . stripslashes($imageType['name']) . '2x.' . 'jpg', (int) $imageType['width'] * 2, (int) $imageType['height'] * 2, 'jpg');
                }
            }
```

Full code is:

```
    if(array_key_exists('images', $ps16ProductObject['product']['associations'])) {
        foreach($ps16ProductObject['product']['associations']['images'] as $imagePs16Id) {
            $image = new \Image();
            $image->id_product = (int) $ps16ProductObject['product']['id'];
            $image->position = \Image::getHighestPosition($ps16ProductObject['product']['id']) + 1;             

            if (!\Image::getCover($image->id_product)) {
                $image->cover = 1;
            } else {
                $image->cover = 0;
            }

            $image->add();
            $new_path = $image->getPathForCreation();                           
            $tmpfile = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../temp.jpg';
            $ps16image = $this->ps16Client->get([
                'resource'      => 'images/products/' . $ps16ProductObject['product']['id'] . '/' . $imagePs16Id['id']
            ]); 
            file_put_contents($tmpfile, $ps16image);
            \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '.' . 'jpg', null, null, 'jpg', false);

            $imagesTypes = \ImageType::getImagesTypes('products');
            $generate_hight_dpi_images = (bool) \Configuration::get('PS_HIGHT_DPI');

            foreach ($imagesTypes as $imageType) {
                \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '-' . stripslashes($imageType['name']) . '.' . 'jpg', $imageType['width'], $imageType['height'], 'jpg');
                if ($generate_hight_dpi_images) {
                    \ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $new_path . '-' . stripslashes($imageType['name']) . '2x.' . 'jpg', (int) $imageType['width'] * 2, (int) $imageType['height'] * 2, 'jpg');
                }
            }

            unlink($tmpfile);

        }
    }
```